# How to create a custom Django admin to replace the existing Django admin?

Tags: python, django-admin

I want to replace the default Django Admin templates with my own completely custom Django admin. The data in the Dashboard should be populated from the DB. How do I work with templated files? Which files should be overridden ?

Answer (score 1):

you can override the django admin template by creating a a new template folder in your base app and inside that folder create another admin folder, and then create a base_site.html and at top {% extends "admin/base.html" %}